# What is equivalent to "jQuery.on" in plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, events

What is the equivalent of the following code in javascript

```
$("body").on("PhantomInitEvent", function(){
                getReviewData();
                supplies_onFocus();
            });
```

`$("body").trigger("PhantomInitEvent");`

Comment: You mean using the native DOM API, and not jQuery, right? Since of course it's already JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

It's already in JavaScript. If, however, you mean what it would look like without jQuery:

```
document.body.addEventListener("PhantomInitEvent", function() {
    getReviewData();
    supplies_onFocus();
});
```

Comment: document.addEventListener("PhantomInitEvent", function(e) {

                window.alert("Mika"+e.detail);
                getReviewData();
                supplies_onFocus();
            });                                                       i am triggering the event like this // Create the event
        var event = new CustomEvent("PhantomInitEvent", { "detail": "Example of an event" });
        window.alert("Banthu"+event);
        // Dispatch/Trigger/Fire the event
        document.dispatchEvent(event);                              it is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
element.attachEvent('onPhantomInitEvent', handler);

element.addEventListener('PhantomInitEvent', handler, false);
```